# Способы блокировки объекта

Tags: java, многопоточность, коллекции

Здравствуйте. У меня такая проблема: В приложении множество потоков бегают случайный образом по MultiValueMap у которой в качестве value используется какой-то Collection. Эти потоки берут из Map'а коллекцию, извлекают из неё элемент,удаляют его из коллекции и обрабатывают. Если коллекция пустая то поток сабмитит таск на обновления коллекции для данного ключа в спец. пул. Этот пул содержит единственный поток, который и обновляет коллекции по ключу. Проблема заключается в том, что возможна такая ситуация когда несколько потоков достают по ключу одну и ту же коллекцию,она оказывается пустая, и сабмитят по сути один и тот-же таск на обновление. Я хочу этого избежать.Грубо говоря хотелось бы чтобы все выглядело так:

```
Collection coll = myMap.getCollection(key);
if(coll.isLocked()) {
// Коллекция залочена, следовательно её не трогаем а переходим к коллекции для другого ключа
} 
if(coll.isEmty()) {
coll.lock()// блокируем коллекцию чтобы никакой другой поток не мог к ней    //обратиться, следовательно не мог получить для ней isEmpty() и засабмитить //таск на выполнение
pool.submit(new MyTask(coll));
}
```

Так будет происходить в потоках-обработчиках. А в потоке обновителе что-то в этом роде:

```
...
//Обносвили коллекцию
coll.unLock(); // Сняли блокировку,теперь потоки обработчики снова могут обращаться к коллекции
```

Вопрос: как такой функционал реализовать правильно? (отнаследоваться от какой-то коллекции и сделать volatile флаг lock. как-то сильно просто) + Учитывая специфику задачи посовеетуйте,пожалуйста, collection для мапа? Беря во внимание что из коллекции элементы нужно удалять, как-то не хочется использовать для таких целей ArrayList, из-за возможных тормозов с System.arrayCopy(...)

Comment: Эта тема ведь обсуждалась же уже? <br/>
PS: Bдея с блокировкой коллекции - nicht gut. Не говоря уже о том, чтобы не дай бог наследовать коллекцию.

Comment: Обсуждалась. Я описывал задачу. Но вопросы задавал по другим проблемам

Comment: Кстати код выше всё равно не правильный, даже если бы коллекция имела lock.

Comment: Ну понятно. Я набросал так, на ломанном псовдокоде, чтобы суть проблемы стала ясней. Почему нельзя отнаследоваться от коллекции ? Это пока единственное что приходит в голову. Отнаследоваться от коллекции. Там сделать флаг lock, и его проверять в потоках-обработчиках и ставить в false в потоке-обновителе.

Comment: @Vladimir, раньше этот Ващ вопрос на глаза не попадался. 

У Вас для один обработчик в пуле для **всех** ключей ? Или несколько (для каждого ключа один обработчик) могут параллельно работать ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можно сделать так:

```
class SafeCollectionContainer<T>
{
   private final Map < String, T > safeMap = new HashMap < String, T > ();
   private final Object locker = new Object ();

   public T safeRead ( final String key )
   {
      synchronized ( locker )
      {
         return safeMap.get ( key );
      }
   }

   /**
    * Safely updates collection found by key
    * 
    * @return result of the update operation
    */
   public boolean safeUpdate ( final String key, final CollectionUpdater < T > updater )
   {
      synchronized ( locker )
      {
         // get item to update
         final T value = safeMap.get ( key );
         if ( null == value )
         {
            return false;
         }

         return updater.update ( value );
      }
   }
}
```

здесь блок один общий на весь контейнер, если нужно блокировать каждую коллекцию отдельно то можно выполнять синхронизацию по самих value или же хранить локер обьект для каждой из них.